# atomic_thread_fence is not a member of std

Tags: c++

Compiling with:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pthread test2.cc -o hello
```

I'm getting this error:

```
test2.cc: atomic_thread_fence is not a member of std
```

I am using g++ 4.5.2 in Ubuntu. What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like an external library - have you installed it according to its documentation? And are you using it like its described in the documentation?

Comment: Add the source of `test2.cc` to the question.

Comment: it is an example from a book , it write std::atomic_thread_fence

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following in test2.cc?

```
#include <atomic>
```